# tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath returns nil with too many cells (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

So I have the weirdest thing;

I am looping a tableView in order to iterate over all cells. It works fine with less than 5 cells, but crashes with "unexpectedly found nil" for more cells. Here's the code:

```
    for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
      for row in 0..<tableView.numberofRowsInSection(section) {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
        let cell = tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? MenuItemTableViewCell

        // extract cell properties
```

The last line is the one that gives the error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you iterating over the cells? You should already have all of the cell data in your data source.

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath may return nil if there isn't a current cell allocated for that path. Offscreen rows, for example. As @rmaddy says, you probably don't need to do this. Don't confuse the tableview method that you are calling here with the data source method that you will have implemented

Comment: cellForRowAtIndex returns optional because the cell may not be yet created like rmaddy said so try if let...

Comment: you're right. the problem is with the nonvisible cells probably. so how would I go about looping the data source instead? (sorry swift / xcode newbie here..).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because cells are reused, cellForRowAtIndexPath will give you cell only if cell for given indexPath is currently visible. It is indicated by the optional value. If you want to prevent from crash, you should use if let

```
if let cell = tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? MenuItemTableViewCell {
     // Do something with cell
}
```

If you want to update values from cell, your cells should update the dataSource items. For example you can create delegate for that

```
protocol UITableViewCellUpdateDelegate {
    func cellDidChangeValue(cell: UITableViewCell)
}
```

Add delegate to your cell and suppose we have a textField in this cell. We add target for the `didCHangeTextFieldValue:` for EditingDidChange event so it is called every time the user types somethink in it. And when he do, we call the delegate function.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    var delegate: UITableViewCellUpdateDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        textField.addTarget(self, action: Selector("didCHangeTextFieldValue:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    }

    @IBAction func didCHangeTextFieldValue(sender: AnyObject?) {
        self.delegate?.cellDidChangeValue(cell)
    }
}
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you add the delegate

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

And finally we implement the delegate method:

```
func cellDidChangeValue(cell: UITableViewCell) {

    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) else {
        return
    }

    /// Update data source - we have cell and its indexPath

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thx this helps me but I still need some more clarity. Do i create the (protocol) delegate in the cell or the viewController? Also, I want to monitor quantity in each cell so can I make the delegate of type Int rather than the cell? Or I still need the cell type so that I get the id of each cell when it's time to dequeue?