# UITableViewCell is nil when not visible in a large UITableView (Xcode, iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessorytype

I've made a large `UITableView` with 27 static `UITableViewCell`s. When selecting a `UITableViewCell` it should set its `accessoryType` to `UITableViewAccessoryCheckmark` and the last selected `UITableViewCell`'s `accessoryType` to `UITableViewAccessoryNone`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  // get an NSInteger from NSUserDefaults

  [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:savedInteger inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
  [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:savedInteger inSection:0]];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  // get the NSInteger again

  UITableViewCell *lastCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:savedInteger inSection:0]];
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  lastCell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryNone;
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryCheckmark;

  // save indexPath.row in NSUserDefaults and do some other stuff
```

This works fine when you select a `UITableViewCell` that is near to the last selected `UITableViewCell` but when the last selected `UITableViewCell` is about 11 rows or so away, the `UITableViewCell *lastCell` is `nil` and the checkmark doesn't disappear.

Why does it behave like that and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't explicitly call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: You should set the accessoryType of a cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: have 1 bool in your model object , and from that bool u can handle accessoryView . if bool is true then show it , otherwise don't ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***cellForRowAtIndexPath*** returns *nil* if cell is not visible or index path is out of range.
Therefore, check whether the currently selected cell is visible.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // get the NSInteger from NSUserDefaults
    NSIndexPath *previousSelection = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:savedInteger inSection:0];
    if ([tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:previousSelection]) {
        UITableViewCell *lastCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousSelection];
        lastCell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryNone;
    }

    // save indexPath.row in NSUserDefaults

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryCheckmark;

    // do other stuff
}
```

Also, in order to ensure that the table view cells are created with the desired *accessoryType* in the first place, set the *accessoryType* of the table view cell in *cellForRowAtIndexPath*.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // get the table view cell and set the details

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryNone;

    // get the NSInteger from NSUserDefaults
    if (indexPath.row == savedInteger) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryCheckmark; 
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cellForRowAtIndexPath returns only visible cell because UITableView reuses cells (it initializes only few cells when you scroll the cell from top goes to bottom and so on, it's efficient)

see similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748447/tableview-cellforrowatindexpath-returns-nil-with-too-many-cells-swift/32748935#32748935)