# CellForRow return nil when the cell are invisible

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I just figured out that `tableView.cellForRow(at: index)` returns nil when the cell is not visible. Is there any way to get the cell even if it's dequeued?

**Edit:** 
 What I want to achieve is a custom copy that will copy the content of all selected cells. For example when the cell with the row equal to 3 is selected, I show a UIMenuController that shows a copy button. If then the cell with row 20 is selected, all cells between 3 and 20 will be selected and the UIMenuController will be enabled in the cell number 20. When I click the copy menu I get the cells content from the data source.

Everything is working fine but some times I am getting an UnsafeMutableRawPointer exception when I click on the copy menu. I don't exactly know when did the error happens. I am trying to find the problem and think that the function is being called on a cell that was released or maybe when I try to access a cell with tableView.cellForRow(at: index).

Comment: "Is there any way to get an object that doesn't exist?" Nope...

Comment: mention some code.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. Why do you think you need to get a cell that isn't visible? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: There is no cell when its invisible. If you need the data for the cell, ask your datasource for that index.

Comment: That's normal. Cells are reused. You are misunderstanding how it should be done. Why it returns nil? Because it could already have been reused and "assigned" to another IndexPath. Explain what you want to do, and we may provide a solution (in general, it's about saving a data in an other object, or modifying the data source and potentially its structure).

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32748935/7250862

Comment: This is is how table views work.  Usually you do not want the cell, you want some information that is contained in the cell.  The only case you actually want a UITableViewCell or a subclass of it, is when you render it, which is what the table view does for you. Which case have you got? You need the UITableVIewCell OR you need information contained in the cell?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Can you share your code that causes the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to copy the data from the cells - copy the data from your datasource (which drives the creation of cells).

You can access the selected rows `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()` and then look to your datasource to provide the content of the cells.